# Stack comparison lemma

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

**Edit.** I am realising that I was asking the wrong question. I was (without knowing it) interested in stack comparison lemmata similar to the lemma $$Sh(Sh(C,J),can) = Sh(C,J)$$
for sheaves. So my question changes to: Which morphisms of sites induce 2-equivalences of the associated 2-categories of stacks? (my stacks are not necessarily fibered in groupoids)

**Old Question.**

Say I have a base category $\mathscr S = Sh(\mathbf C,J)$ of sheaves on a small site and I want to look at fibrations above $\mathscr S$. Assume $\mathbb F$ is a fibration above $\mathscr S$. What are the relations between the following conditions:

1. The fibration $\mathbb F$ is a stack with respect to the regular topology on $\mathscr S$, whose covers are generated by single regular epimorphisms $u: V \twoheadrightarrow U$.
2. The fibration $\mathbb F$ is a stack with respect to the coherent topology on $\mathscr S$. The covers in the coherent topology are generated by finite families $\{u_i: U_i \to U\}$ such that the images of the $u_i$ jointly cover $U$.
3. The fibration $\mathbb F$ satisfies effective descent with respect to the coproduct inclusions of finite coproducts. I believe that this is the (finitary) extensive topology.
4. The fibration $\mathbb F$ satisfies effective descent with respect to the coproduct inclusions of arbitrary coproducts.
5. The restriction of $\mathbb F$ to the small category $\mathbf C$ is a stack with respect to the topology $J$.
6. The fibration $\mathbb F$ is a stack with respect to the canonical topology on $\mathscr S$. The covers of the canonical topology are generated by small jointly regular epimorphic families of morphisms.

Is it for example correct that 1. and 4. together are equivalent to 6.?

Comment: Yes. Actually this is just a question of whether the specified families generate the same Grothendieck topology, since you can show that the families that a presheaf satisfies descent for form a Grothendieck topology.

Comment: @ZhenLin That makes sense. What about 5.? Can I check that $\mathbb F$ is a stack on the site?

Comment: No. For example, take $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{1}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, yeah, right. Then $\mathscr S = Set$. Thanks!

Comment: It's tricky when you start allowing $n$-categories as sites for $n > 1$. Then Grothendieck topologies are not enough to capture all left exact reflections.

Comment: @ZhenLin But when my sites are 1-categories then it will work as for sheaves?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure. There are issues with sheaves of ∞-groupoids but I think for $n$-groupoids ($n < \infty$) on a 1-site it is determined by what happens with sheaves of sets.